# Android custom keyboard - How to detect requested keyboard type

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Following [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) I have created a fully working Android OS keyboard. it is a standard qwerty alpha/numeric.

I have a second keyboard mark-up for numeric keyboard.

What I can't seem to detect is what type of keyboard is being specified by the text input box.  The edittext specifies the type
`editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);`
but how does my IME service detect this so it can present the correct keyboard?

```
public class MyKeybdIME extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {
    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    private Keyboard numboard;
    private boolean caps = false;
    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (MKeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwertyfull);
        numboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.num);

//        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//How can you detect what is being asked for?       
//        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
// Or am I on the wrong path for this part?


        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);//... Or numboard when the entry requests a numeric keyboard
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `onStartInput` in your custom keyboard class. Here is a the relevant code taken from the [sample Android keyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java#147):

```
@Override public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    // ...

    switch (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
            // ...
            break;
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:
            // ...
            break;
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:
            // ...
            break;
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```